# Having a Chassidishe Gaiva

Tags: halacha, parshanut-torah-comment, talmud-gemara, commentaries

BH

One of my teachers said once that a student of the Alter Rebbe was in a city  filled with so much materialism and sin that he was later asked how he was able to overcome the tests and so he said "I just pulled out my Chassidishe Gaiva (Hasidic pride) saying what me? One of the Alter Rebbe's Chassidim falling to such a low level? A Bachir Shebe Nivraim (the choicest of creations)?" And because he used this method of being proud of his high status he was able to over come the tests in the city.

So is this the same concept that a person should have a 60th of pride and if yes what are more sources of this concept of having good pride like this in Shas?

Comment: [Sotah 5a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.5a.16?lang=bi): "א"ר חייא בר אשי אמר רב ת"ח צריך שיהא בו אחד משמונה בשמינית".

Comment: @Fred That's about preserving authority.